# Suppose we know $f(A)$ is similar to $f(B)$ does it follow that $A$ is similar to $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of same dimension and $f$ a polynomial and assume $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ non zero.
Suppose we know $f(A)$ is similar to $f(B)$ does it follow that $A$ is similar to $B$?

Comment: What if $f$ is a constant function?

Comment: Suppose $f$ is the function $f(X) = I$....

Comment: you are right, I haven't thought of that

Comment: doesn't even need to be constant, take $x^2$ and $Id$, $-Id$

Comment: @mm-aops $f$ is a polynomial, so a "constant function" means a constant multiple of $I$.

Comment: yeah, and I'm saying $f$ doesn't have to be constant, I'm saying that counterexamples exist for $f(A) := A^2$ for example